# Will I lose my progress when updating to PE Version 0.10.4?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When updating Minecraft Pocket Edition to the newer version, will I lose my creations? Will my inventory reset?

Please help because I spent many days building my world.

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft PE updates **do not** reset/delete user worlds. 
However, certain features included in Minecraft updates will not be included in existing worlds, such as new terrain generation or blocks. You will have to create a new world for this.